# Haskell odbc driver failing to connect due to backslash in domain

Tags: sql-server, haskell

I am having an issue trying to connect to a Microsoft sql server using Haskell and the obdc driver. here is the code I have

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module Lib
  ( someFunc
  ) where

import Data.Text (Text, pack, singleton, snoc)
import qualified Data.Text.IO as T
import Database.ODBC.SQLServer

someFunc :: IO ()
someFunc = do
  conn <-
    connect
      ("DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=example;Uid=domain\\test;Pwd=test")
  rows <- query conn "SELECT TOP 100 * FROM test with (nolock)" :: IO [[Value]]
  print rows
  close conn
```

when I run the program it trys to connect to the database with the Uid = domain\\test instead of what I want which is domain\test, I tried alot of different things to try and build the connection string and they all end up with a \\ between the domain and the username. I was wondering if anyone has dealt with this before?

Note: if the user id does not have a backslash in it it does work.

Answer (score 1):

If you need two backslashes in a string, you have to escape them both in Haskell (as in C, and most programming languages). Try using

```
"...;Uid=domain\\\\test;..."
```

Comment: I need to have only one backslash that is my problem. sorry if my question was poorly worded.

Comment: @LCochranBjerke Your Haskell string currently has exactly one backslash. I wonder if `connect` for some reason expects some quoting, so we need to double that. Did you try using two backslashes in the string (four in Haskell), to see what happens, anyway?

Comment: this is what I get when I try the string above "DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=example;Uid=domain\\test;Pwd=test" UnsuccessfulReturnCode "odbc_SQLDriverConnect" (-1) "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user ' domain\\test'.[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'domain\\test'." and here is what I get when I do 4 slashes Login failed for user 'domain\\\\test'

Comment: @LCochranBjerke OK. I think the log message is re-escaping the username, so it actually has one and two backslashes, even if it's printed with two and four.  My guess is that the issue lies somewhere else, not in the backslashes.